# how to include a yandex API JAVA files into an android project

Tags: java, gradle, import, classpath

I have the Yandex API files that have JAVA code, I would like to import it into an Android Project. I cant wrap my head around how to include the attached into a simple project.

It states the following in README.MD file : "Provides a Java wrapper around the Yandex machine translation web service API." 
The folder has a . classpath and .project files. i cant seem to relate.

I tried import/export to/from eclipse w/ gradle , but that led me to gradle version conflict which i couldnt get out of. So I tried importing manually and linking using gradle.build using compile files("..") or import.

I need to be able to call this set of cluster files which will return an output. they are located seperate inside my app folder.

I can simply take java pieces and include them in my code but i want to learn the proper simplified forms.

Im newbie. So all tips will help.

[Location of the YANDEX API website](https://tech.yandex.com/translate/doc/dg/reference/getLangs-docpage/)

[Yandex api download zip file](https://backup.filesanywhere.com/fs/v.aspx?v=8d6b62885e6175b7a5ae)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you speak about this project https://github.com/rmtheis/yandex-translator-java-api, I don't think you should use it.
It doesn't implement all Yandex API features and it's not developing now.

You can call Yandex API directly through REST libraries like Retrofit.

If you really need to use this library, you could build JAR-file by this

```
git clone https://github.com/rmtheis/yandex-translator-java-api
cd yandex-translator-java-api
change src/com/rmtheis/yandtran/ApiKeys.java  
      protected static -> public static
mkdir build
javac -d build -cp "libs/*" -sourcepath src/ src/com/rmtheis/yandtran/detect/Detect.java
cd build
jar -cfv ../yandex-translator-api.jar com/
```

Then you can add yandex-translator-api.jar and libs/json_simple-1.1.jar to your project

Comment: ok great. atleast i want to generate my the .JAR and call a method. then I will switch to a better translator API .. Any Translator API's in mind. 
Google charges much. I might go with BING

Comment: @MohsenMouralli so, set this is answered if it solved this problem

Comment: But from the looks of it the API is not even responding to requests since my translate.translation is null and following it back to uc.getinputstream is null (tracing it its idling)